# Creating a python module for distribution from a single shared library file

Tags: python, distutils

I have a shared library that I have created using pybind11.

called dddd.so

when I open python and type

```
import dddd
print(dddd.test_function())
```

I get my desired result, and that's fantastic.

However, my goal is to create a conda installable package, so that I could create a conda environment, and then type:

```
conda install dddd
```

And have that work.

So I am trying to create a setup.py file that will allow me to create this using python setup.py bdist or python setup.py bdist_conda

I have not been able to get my shared library to go into a bdist module.

My directory structure at the moment is

```
dddd/
    - dddd/
           -dddd.so
           -__init__.py
setup.py
```

I have tried a lot of things, including [Distribute a Python package with a compiled dynamic shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316177/distribute-a-python-package-with-a-compiled-dynamic-shared-library)
 , but I have not been able to get it to work.

When I try this as my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name='dddd',
    version='0.2',
    packages=['dddd'],
    package_dir={'dddd': 'dddd'},
    package_data={'dddd': ['dddd.so']},
)
```

I am able to get python setup.py bdist_conda to work.

However when I run this conda module, my module can now not be directly accessed, I have to do:

```
import dddd.dddd
dddd.dddd.test_function()
```

Which is not what I want.

I can't seem to achieve what was achieved in the answer in my link.

Comment: Why is this tagged `C++` and `pybind11`?

Comment: So it is a precompiled shared object. Make `dddd` to a package by adding an `__init__.py`, add `dddd` to `packages` list in `setup.py` and include `dddd.so` via `package_data` like described in the question you linked. `Extension`s are used when you have the source code for the shared library and compile it to shared object when building the distribution.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks, have updated with package_data, but can't seem to directly access my module

Comment: This is exactly what is done in the linked question. If you want to place the shared object directly to site-packages, then your best bet is to build it from C sources by declaring an `Extension`. You can only place python modules or `Extension`s in the site-packages root; although there are some (hacky) ways to circumvent that, they all have exceptions and won't work in all situations.

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare imports in the `__init__.py` file, something like `from .dddd import test_function`, so it is already imported at the `dddd` package level; this way, you should be able to do `import dddd; dddd.test_function()` in the calling modules.

Comment: @hoefling the command `from .dddd import test_function` in init.py achieves the end result I am after, although I guess it means I have to write that for every function in my dddd.so file. At least it works. If you want to put that comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Sure, it's a major drawback as you need to keep your `__init__.py` consistent on changes; but why don't you want to build the shared object from C source code by configuring an `Extension`? This would be the most straightforward way IMO. Should you need a prebuilt shared object in `dddd` for development, you can always build one via `python setup.py build_ext`. You would then also eliminate the need of the `dddd` package completely and your imports would work by default.

Comment: @hoefling yes an extension would probably be a better way to do this. I will probably head in this direction. My initial reluctance was that I already build my project using a build system (meson) and I didn't want to go down the path of having another file where I needed to specify include directories, source files etc.. but comparing that hassle to maintaining an init.py and it's not much different. I could either get my setup.py file to use pkg-config or use a [custom target](http://mesonbuild.com/Generating-sources.html) in meson to streamline my process

Comment: Interesting - last time I checked, `meson` couldn't start anything with Python projects (funny because it's written in Python itself). Now it looks like [some rudimentary support was implemented](http://mesonbuild.com/Python-module.html). I'm curious whether it's enough to build wheels with `meson`? Wheels don't need a setup script, all you need is to generate valid package metadata files (dist-info). Looks like one could write a custom target that generates the metadata, then zip the shared object along with the metadata, rename zip to wheel and done.