# How to install dynamic library using setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I want to distribute a Python package which has a closed source dependency. I am using setup.py and everything works if I also do the compilation with setup.py.

Neither answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py) nor answers to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316177/distribute-a-python-package-with-a-compiled-dynamic-shared-library) solve my problem.

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── closed_source
│   ├── compiled.so
├── python_modules
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

I also tried to include `compiled.so` in `python_modules`. In `file1.py` I use `import compiled` which fails.

The following works, but silently fails to include the dynamic library:

```
setup(
    name='my_package',
    version=0.1,
    packages=['python_modules'],
    package_dir={'python_modules': 'python_modules'},
    package_data={'': ['closed_source/compiled.so']}, # also tried using key compiled
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `compiled.so` in the `python_modules` folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.

Comment: your import is incorrect, it should be `from python_modules import compiled` if it's included inside the package

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yes, that worked. I used `import python_modules.compiled as compiled` after putting `compiled.so` in the `python_modules` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to [vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26217488/1547004) the dependency. The easiest way to do that is to include the dependency *inside* your python package, not outside.

`setuptools` requires you to include a [`MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) file to include non-package, non-python files in your distribution.

See [this](https://github.com/navdeep-G/setup.py) project for an example of how to do that.

Your project structure should look something like this:

```
my_package
|-- vendor
    |-- compiled.so
|-- __init__.py
|-- file1.py
|-- file2.py
setup.py
```

You would also need to import your vendored library using the additional relative prefix

```
from .vendor import compiled
```

Comment: Perfect, worked. It actually works without a `Manifest.in` file.

Comment: @Niki It's possible `setuptools` recognizes your file extension as a package file. For resource files like txt, jpg, json, etc., it normally won't pick them up by default.